# Componente DatePicker quebrando a tela na edição

Tags: javascript, react, datepicker

Criei o seguinte componente para selecionar datas no UnForm:

```
export default function DatePickerInput({ name, ...rest }) {
  const datepickerRef = useRef(null);
  const { fieldName, defaultValue = '', registerField } = useField(name);

  const [date, setDate] = useState(defaultValue || null);
  useEffect(() => {
    registerField({
      name: fieldName,
      ref: datepickerRef.current,
      path: 'props.selected',
    });
  }, [fieldName, registerField]);

  return (
    <Label htmlFor={fieldName}>
      <UnInput>
        <ReactDatePicker
          ref={datepickerRef}
          selected={date}
          onChange={setDate}
          dateFormat="dd/MM/yyyy"
          placeholderText="dd/mm/aaaa"
          writable="true"
          {...rest}
        />
      </UnInput>
    </Label>
  );
}
```

Para salvar registros o componente está funcionando normalmente, carregando e salvando a data que eu selecionei. Quando vou editar um registro, ao tentar carregar a data no load inicial, a página é quebrada e é exibido o seguinte erro:

```
Unhandled Rejection (TypeError): Cannot assign to read only property 'selected' of object '#<Object>'
```

Se eu comento a linha `path: 'props.selected'`, no `useEfect()` a tela não é quebrada, porém a data não é preenchida no componente.
Como fazer para funcionar ?

Comment: Não sei é isso, mas já tentou usar `writable="true"` com o valor `true` sem as aspas: `writable=true`? Já vi plugins que tratam `"true"` (entre aspas) como string e `true` (sem aspas) como booleano e causa diferenciação e comportamento incorreto quando é string.

Comment: Ele não aceita.

Comment: Sem um exemplo [reproduzível](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) não é possível ajudar. Você não mostrou nem os `import`'s para alguém poder tentar reproduzir. Parece que está usando o [`react-datepicker`](https://github.com/Hacker0x01/react-datepicker/blob/master/docs/datepicker.md), mas nem isso posso afirmar, já que ele não tem uma prop `writable`.

Comment: @RafaelTavares sim. Estou usando o  react-datepicker. Postei os códigos completos aqui nestes dois Gists: https://gist.github.com/raphaelpradoo/aa301509820d78b726ff8ac258e750a1 https://gist.github.com/raphaelpradoo/ed20a035777a37bdc5d370f2fef699c9

Answer (score 0):

**Problema :**

`formRef.current.setFieldValue('birthday',value)` isso tentará definir valor no caminho fornecido, no nosso caso, desde que `path` seja `props.selected`

E `props.selected` é uma propriedade somente leitura, portanto você não pode definir valor em `props`, daí o erro.

```
useEffect(() => {
    registerField({
      name: fieldName,
      ref: datepickerRef.current,
      path: 'props.selected', // <---- this is props, and it's readonly
      clearValue: (ref) => {
        ref.clear();
      },
    });
}, [fieldName, registerField]);
```

---

**Solução :**

Você pode remover o `path` e usar os métodos`getter` e `setter`, nomeados como`getValue` e `setValue`:

`setValue` : para definir o valor inicial ou o que passou de `setFieldValue`

`getValue` :  para obter valor ao enviar

```
useEffect(() => {
    registerField({
      name: fieldName,
      ref: datepickerRef.current,
      clearValue: ref => {
        ref.clear();
      },
      setValue: (e, v) => {
        setDate(new Date(v)); // <---- Setting up default value 
      },
      getValue: () => {
        return datepickerRef.current.props.selected; // to get selected value from Date picker's props
        // OR
        return Date.toString(); // to get selected value from state it self
      }
    });
}, [fieldName, registerField]);
```

**DEMO DE TRABALHO** :

[image: Edit #SO-Datepicker-unform-setvalue]

Comment: Any reason for downvote?

Comment: Because this is the StackOverflow in Portuguese. This community is exclusively for Lusophone users so questions and answers should be asked in Portuguese. If you want to continue communicating in English, you can use [StackOverflow EN](https://stackoverflow.com/).

Comment: Okay thanks man,for explaining, let me convert it into Portuguese,

Comment: Do you need help with that?

Comment: @AugustoVasques,I know answer is 100% correct but I think,getting downvotes just for a language, I've tried to convert it, will you please also check if its still understandable or you can update it, thanks for asking.

Comment: it's OK(está OK).

Comment: @AugustoVasques, Thanks man (obrigado cara) :)

Answer (score -2):

> writable="true"

No JSX, para inserir um valor booleano, entre outros , deve-se inserí-lo entre chaves ex. `writable={true}`,

Comment: Continua com o mesmo problema